# Draw on a canvas and write in a content editable div mantaining the drawing on top of the div

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, contenteditable

I'm writing a sort of WYSISYG tool where I can write and draw at the same time. **I need the drawing to be "on top" of the writing**.

The writing element is a content editable `div`, the drawing is a `canvas`.
To switch from drawing to texting and vice versa there's a button, which in fact toggles the `zIndex` of the two elements. Everything works fine, but to make it work properly **I need to have the drawing ALWAYS on top**, which won't happen if I toggle the `zIndex`. If I don't toggle the `zIndex` back for `writing mode` I can't access anymore the `div` with the content editable (which would be behind the `canvas`), but if I switch it the drawing goes background (which must not happen). How can fix this?

The code that I use when you press the `Drawing/Typing` button is:

```
    function switchDrawingText(){

    var tempTextBox = document.getElementById("textBox");
    var tempCanvas = document.getElementById("toolCanvas");

    tempCanvas.style.zIndex *= -1;
    tempTextBox.style.zIndex *= -1;

}
```

I also tried to play a little with `pointer-events: none;` but with no luck.

While in `drawing mode` the result it's ok:

[image: this is ok]

but when I switch back to `writing mode` the `canvas` goes in the background, which is not what I need:

[image: not ok]

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the canvas to **pointer-events: none;** Then, you will have to have a div with the same size as canvas on top of the canvas. This div **will receive the mouse events** instead of the canvas but you will still draw canvas. So you will have your contenteditable div with **zIndex 1**, the div for receiving the mouse events **zIndex 2**, and the canvas with **zIndex 3**.

```
canvas.style.zIndex = 3;
divForWritting.style.zIndex = 1;
forMouseEvents.style.zIndex = 2;
```

Now the user is able to draw canvas. If you want to let the user write on the contenteditable div, you just set the contenteditable div's zIndex at 2 and the div that receives the events to 1 :

```
canvas.style.zIndex = 3;
divForWritting.style.zIndex = 2;
forMouseEvents.style.zIndex = 1;
```

This way canvas always stays on top.

Check out a quick demo I made :

https://jsfiddle.net/jyt1cy40/

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helps me. I saw the example and it's exactly what I need. I will try to implement it in my code and see what happens. Cheers!

Comment: @devamat I am glad I helped! If you think my answer helped you please click on the check mark on the left of my answer.

Comment: Done. Thanks again.